# int pointer to the .end() of a list

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, linked-list

I am currently working on creating a header file that acts like the standard library. I am in the progress of implemeing .end() for my linked list. In my cpp file I have an integer pointer which is expected to recieve the value of the .end() like

```
int* itrend;
itrend = ca.end();
```

`ca` is just an instance of my object in my header file.
In my hpp file, I have a list iterator going to my `listofvalues.end()`. I would like to return the `.end()` value like

```
int* end() 
{
    std::list<value_type>::iterator i = listOfValues.end();
    return (&*i);

}
```

My "List of values" is just a list holding several ints. eg

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

In my hpp file, I have a list iterator going to my `listofvalues.end()`. I would like to return the `.end()` value (which returns a list iterator); now this posess a problem that it returns the list iterator when I want to have an integer pointer. I have tried to deference it and take the address by using `&*` and this will give an error saying  "List Iterator Not Dereferencable". I know it's because I'm trying to get the element after the last value, but that is exactly what I need to return, since I am trying to re-implement the linked list `.end()` method.

Does anyone know how I can have an integer pointer point to the `List.end()`?

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To implement `begin()` and `end()` in a style similar to STL return `iterator`s, not pointers:

```
template <typename value_type>
class my_list
{
public:
    typedef std::list<value_type>::iterator iterator;
    typedef std::list<value_type>::const_iterator const_iterator;

    iterator begin() { return listofValues.begin(); }
    const_iterator begin() const { return listofValues.begin(); }


    iterator end() { return listofValues.end(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return listofValues.end(); }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The way we need to have it is to return an int*. Do you know if there is a way we can have this iterator you have implemented converted to an int*?

Comment: @SSS - If you need it to return an `int *` your interface is broken. What `int *` could it possibly return (other than `(int *)0`, which means something else and shouldn't really be used for this purpose since you'd have to rewrite your code)?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. That's why the standard library containers are *more general* than a flat array. In a C-style array, you can form the pointer one-past-the end (although you are not allowed to dereference it) and use it as a sentinel. In a more abstract container, there is no such "natural" mechanic, which is why iterators were invented in the first place: They are a generalization of pointers that works in more general contexts. Each container's iterator type must solve the problem of providing a suitable "end" sentinel value in its own way.

Answer (score 2):

how do you use your own impementaton of end() anyway? why not returning null when iterator whould return end() ?

```
int* end() 
{
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: This is how we have it now, but we didn't see the purpose of just returning a null. Because the .end of a list returns the iterator type, we were trying to return a pointer to the element just behind the last value. @luskan

Answer (score 0):

The idea of representing the end of the a Linked list with a pointer is somewhat flawed, because you can't progress a pointer with ++ in a linked list, it doesn't iterate through anything.

If you you want to get the back of a list implement `l.back()` and return a reference to the last value.